# How to do pagination using groupby in vespa.ai?

Tags: vespa

I have tried below query-

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/search/?yql=select * from sources document_name where sddocname contains 'document_name' | all(group(key) each(each(output(summary())))) ;
```

The result I got-

```
{
"root": {
    "id": "toplevel",
    "relevance": 1.0,
    "fields": {
        "totalCount": 2924
    },
    "coverage": {
        "coverage": 100,
        "documents": 2924,
        "full": true,
        "nodes": 3,
        "results": 1,
        "resultsFull": 1
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "group:root:0",
            "relevance": 1.0,
            "continuation": {
                "this": ""
            },
            "children": [
                {...
```

To implement pagination We need `continuation.this` key value, but we are getting empty string inside `this` key that.

Also, How can we set the number of records in a single page in pagination using group by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above example

```
all(group(key) each(each(output(summary()))))
```

Will not have any continuation as you have fetched all unique key groups and all hits for each of the unique keys.

```
all(group(key) max(2) each( max(1) each(output(summary()))))
```

Gives you max 2 key values, and for each of those keys 1 hit. In this case you'll see valid continuations.